# CRM in the context of C++ programming

Tags: c++, crm

I was asked by an employer about CRM in the context of C++ software development.  The position I was applying for was C++ Software Engineer.

I told them:  As far as I know, CRM is an acronym that stands for Customer Relationship Management.  It also refers to software tools that track the responses and actions of customers and employees that are involved in some business relationship.

But they seemed disappointed that I didn't know how to code or implement a CRM framework in C++ and I couldn't seem to find much on the Net either.

Does anyone know what an employer is looking for at this stage - before they hire you and train you up?  I would appreciate some pointers to get started.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like they want a programmer and a business anylist in one package.  They definitely might have trouble finding this person, since the two specialties often do not go hand in hand. **This could be a sign that they are looking to lean on their developers to "come up with a requirements spec"** (which might as well read "must be able to read minds").

Of course, they **might just really want the security that comes with someone who has been around the block in that particular domain before**. However, a CRM is usually not too terribly different then most other "move data around with stored procs, create a few UIs, etc." type business apps, so really any type of enterprise app development experience should be sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that they were hoping you knew CRM and C++ inside out so that you could create a clone of Salesforce.com quickly.  They want the [goose that lays the golden egg.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goose_That_Laid_the_Golden_Eggs)

While you may think they'll train you up, it may be the other way around if the company is hiring expertise in CRM and C++.  Course that is just a guess on my part.

Answer (score 3):

They're probably hoping that you have experience building CRM systems in C++. You have C++ experience and you have a high-level understanding of CRMs. If you have experience (C++ or otherwise) that is relevant to CRMs that might help you...